# IP Address Assignment in ad hoc networks / MANETS

Tags: networking, network-protocols

I would like to use an ad hoc network inside my application and was wondering, if there are some existing techniques / libraries to do that. So far I found, that Zeroconf/AutoIP and JXTA seem to be promising for direct communication inside a ad hoc network. 
However, it would be best, if IP address assignment would work in multi hop ad hoc networks. I found a lot of different research papers addressing the issue of IP assignment in MANETs/multi hop ad hoc networks, but I could not find any "ready to use" implementations. Are there simply no such implementations, even though most of these research papers are from the early 2000s?

Comment: Are you reinventing the TCP/IP stack, or are you building this on top of an existing OS?

Comment: As high level as possible - most likely I will use a minimal Linux (Raspberry Pi)